# When to use textConent and value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently following an HTML+CSS+JS tutorial, and I'm new to these stuff.

I'm super confused with `value` and `textContent`

Here's my experiment:

**setter `textContent` of an `<li>` works ✅**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.button')
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.querySelector('#items').lastElementChild.textContent = 'NEW ITEM NAME'
})
```

---

**getter `textContent` returns empty ❌**

**getter `value` returns with value ✅**

**setter `value` works ✅**

**setter `textContent` does not work ❌**

```
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name')

myForm.addEventListener('submit', onsubmit)

function onsubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  console.log("TEXT CONTENT: " + nameInput.textContent) // empty!
  console.log("VALUE: " + nameInput.value) // with value!

  console.log("SETTING VALUE....")  
  nameInput.value = "varrrrrr" // setter works!

  console.log("SETTING TEXT CONTENT....")

  var delayInMilliseconds = 5000; 
  setTimeout(function() {
    nameInput.textContent = "foooooo" // setter does not work!
    console.log("DONE SETTING TEXT CONTENT!")
  }, delayInMilliseconds);
}
```

So question is, how does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

**textcontent**

> The textContent property of the Node interface represents the text content of the node and its descendants.

```js
let text = document.getElementById('divA').textContent;

document.getElementById('divA').textContent = 'This text is different!';
```

```html
<div id="divA">This is <span>some</span> text!</div>
```

**value**

> But only input elements have a "value". It represent the input data supplied by the user or provided initially by the code. Also, input elements may have a "textContent" property but it will always be empty since they are void elements.

```js
  let result = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  console.log(result)
  
   let val = document.getElementById("myText").value = "Hello World!";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="My text">
```

In your case, `getter textContent returns empty ❌` and `setter textContent does not work ❌` both will not work on the input element as mentioned above.